How to get rid of "Virtual Machine Manager wants to inhibit shortcuts" message?
When I launch virt-manager in Ubuntu 24.04 it opens a dialogue:
Virtual Machine Manager wants to inhibit shortcuts.
You can restore shortcuts by pressing Super+Escape. 

Deny? Allow?

I click Allow, however, I would like to be this automatic (always granted).
Some people suggested I should grant gnome shortcuts-inhibitor permission with flatpak command, HOWEVER, my virt-manager is installed as a DEB package.

with the recent GNOME version non-Flatpak applications may trigger a shortcuts-inhibition dialog when requesting shortcut grabs.
The simplest soution is to disable portal for your application session, we use  a env variable like that:
GTK_USE_PORTAL=0 virt-manager


Unfortunately it is not working. I tried with GTK_USE_PORTAL=0 /usr/bin/virt-viewer -f -w -a MyWindows and I still get this notification... However, I do not get notification if I run virt-viewer with sudo. But this is not safe...

Have you tried putting the variable in your ~/.bashrc ? add this inside export GTK_USE_PORTAL=0 then source ~/.bashrc

No, it is the same.
